# Make a list with multiple matching criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

[image]

Hello, 
I need help extracting information if the criteria are matched. So I need to extract a list for (level) MAG4 if a student received fewer than 8 points or get below 80%, and I need to extract a list for (level) MGT4 if a student received fewer than 25 points or get below 80%. I would like to have one formula that will solve this problem. 
Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Publish some test (example) data safe for experiments (public GoogleTable is safe, for example).

Comment: I think you need to provide a sample

Answer (score 0):

**This array (CSE) formula solves the issue:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `F31`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  ```
  {=INDEX($A$31:$A$49, MATCH(0, IF(OR($G31<$B$31:$B$49, $H31<$C$31:$C$49),COUNTIF($F$30:$F30, $A$31:$A$49), ""), 0))}
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*